# passing weblogic password using EOF

Tags: oracle, weblogic

Here is my code

```
echo "Shutting Down UAT Concurent Manager"

con=`ps -ef | grep appluat |wc -l`

if [ $con -ge 1 ]
then
     echo "Concurrent is up and running, shutting it down......"
     su - appluat -c "/home/UAT2/apps2/fs1/inst/apps/UAT_erp/admin/scripts/adstpall.sh apps/xxxx "
     <<EOF weblogic xxxxx
      EOF"

else
     echo "Concurrent is already down"
fi
```

Why does it throw this error?

> ./shutdown_uat_apps.sh: line 14: warning: here-document at line 9 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
>   ./shutdown_uat_apps.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are starting a here-document, but never close it. To close it, the `EOF` needs to be at the start of the line:

```
 su - appluat -c "/home/UAT2/apps2/fs1/inst/apps/UAT_erp/admin/scripts/adstpall.sh apps/xxxx"
 <<EOF weblogic xxxxx
  EOF"
```

What is your intention with the above code?

To do the syntax fix, you need to change it as follows, but that still doesn't make sense:

```
 su - appluat -c "/home/UAT2/apps2/fs1/inst/apps/UAT_erp/admin/scripts/adstpall.sh apps/xxxx "
 <<EOF weblogic xxxxx
EOF
```

## See also

[Here-documents](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, i want to run crontab to shutdown the application server then the database , but it kept prompting for weblogic password in EBS, any ways i will post the correct code .

Answer (score 0):

It should be within the initial quote `"..."`:

```
  "/home/UAT2/apps2/fs1/inst/apps/UAT_erp/admin/scripts/adstpall.sh 
  apps/xxxxxpassxxx <<EOF
  xxxxpasswordxxxx
  EOF"
```